# How to make pdf using mpdf that have big data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, web, mpdf

I have some problems were using mpdf with a large data.

I'm using Codeigniter as backend framework and the database is SQL Server

I have set the memory limit to -1 =====> `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);`
It works when I have a small data, e.g. 100 rows.

But, now I have 1000 rows and I got this error

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 823394304) (tried to allocate 230352 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\simas\application\third_party\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 14487
```

what's wrong with my code? or how to fix this mpdf?

queries in model :

```
SELECT t.tgl_buku as tglbuku, t.kd_brg as kdbarang, b.namabarang, t.no_aset as qty, t.jns_trn, t.rph_aset as jumlah,t.asal_perlh as asal, t.merk_type as merk, t.keterangan, t.no_bukti as nobukti FROM as_transaksi t join ms_barang b on t.kd_brg = b.kdbarang WHERE t.jns_trn like '1%' and year(t.tgl_buku) = '2013' and month(t.tgl_buku) <= 6
```

table in view :

```
<table width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background:#C0C0FF; text-align:center;">
                    <center>
                    <td>Tgl Buku</td>
                    <td>Kd Barang</td>
                    <td>Nama Barang</td>
                    <td>Qty</td>
                    <td>Nilai</td>
                    <td>Supplier</td>
                    <td>Merk</td>
                    <td>Keterangan</td>
                    </center>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
            if (!empty($isdata)) {
                $total=0;
                foreach ($isdata as $row) {
                    $total=$total+($row->jumlah*$row->qty);
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>". date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row->tglbuku))."</div></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row->kdbarang."</div></td>";
                    echo '<td>'.$row->namabarang."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row->qty."</div></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row->jumlah."</div></td>";
                    echo '<td>'.$row->asal."</td>";
                    echo '<td>'.$row->merk."</td>";
                    echo '<td>'.$row->keterangan."</td>";
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }else{
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="3">Total</td>
                <td><div align="right"><b><?=convertrp($total);?></b></div></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Please someone help me :)

Comment: "Small" technicality. Big data would imply something greater than 200 million rows. With that said, is this all the code?

Comment: I mean for this extraordinary situation, because it will create about 2000 pages if it's printed.

Answer (score 0):

**Why `Out of memory` Occur??**

98% of the time this error comes from loading more into memory than what you set up PHP to handle in one process. There are other causes, but these are much less common — very rarely it can be a memory leak if you're on PHP 5.3 and above.

---

**Solution**

Increase your memory limit

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
```

---

**Any thing to know more about solution(s)?**

1. If by **increasing the memory limit** you have gotten rid of the error
   and your code now works, you'll need to take measures to decrease
   that memory usage. Here are a few things you could do to decrease
   it:
2. If you're reading files, **read them line-by-line instead of reading
   in the complete file into memory**. Look at fgets and
   `SplFileObject::fgets`.
3. **Upgrade to a new version** of PHP if you're using PHP 5.3. **PHP 5.4 and
   5.5 use much less memory**.
4. **Avoid loading large datasets into in an array**. Instead, go for
   processing smaller subsets of the larger dataset and, if necessary,
   persist your data into a database to relieve memory use.
5. Try the **latest version or minor version** of a third-party library
   (1.9.3 vs. your 1.8.2, for instance) and use whichever is more
   stable. Sometimes newer versions of libraries are written more
   efficiently.
6. If you have an u**ncommon or unstable PHP extension, try upgrading it**.
   It might have a memory leak.
7. If you're dealing with **large file**s and you simply can't read it
   line-by-line, **try breaking the file into many smaller files** and
   process those individually.
8. **Disable PHP extensions that you don't need**.
9. In the problem area, **unset variables which contain large amounts of
   data** and aren't required later in the code.

Comment: Not yet, still have this eror message